# body { font-size: 100.01%; } vs body { font-size: 100%; }?

Tags: css, xhtml, cross-browser

What should i keep for `body`, `{font-size: 100.01%; }` or `{ font-size: 100%; }`?

what is `{font-size: 100.01%; }`? and is it really good to mention font-size in `html{}` even

If I'm using  `body {font-size: 62.5%;}`

**Edit : 3 May 2010**

Today i found info about `100.01%` at here - http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?cid=FAF76&print=true

> This odd 100.01% value for the font
>   size compensates for several browser
>   bugs. First, setting a default body
>   font size in percent (instead of em)
>   eliminates an IE/Win problem with
>   growing or shrinking fonts out of
>   proportion if they are later set in
>   ems in other elements. Additionally,
>   some versions of Opera will draw a
>   default font-size of 100% too small
>   compared to other browsers. Safari, on
>   the other hand, has a problem with a
>   font-size of 101%. The current "best"
>   suggestion is to use the 100.01% value
>   for this property.

Is it good to keep `body { font-size:100.01%}` in place of `{font-size:100%}`

Comment: Funny, I saw a very similar post just like this on another forum last night.

Comment: @Sam152 - then, was there any good answer for this , if yes then tell me the link.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The declaration `body (or html) { font-size: 100.01% }` compensates rounding errors, in particular in older versions of Opera and Safari. Both would otherwise display fonts that are too small.

A relative font-size (%, em) is always interpreted relative to the font size of the parent element. So it's not a bad idea to implement kind of a initial reset in the top element, which you can achieve with `body {font-size: 100%}`.

Answer (score 4):

Never seen 100.01% before, but it seems like some sort of browser hack that will force some browsers to ignore or calculate size correct if you use this "fix".

I wouldn't use it myself though, as errors tends to be fixed and there are often more nice ways of dealing with the same option.

Answer (score 0):

html    {
    font-size: 100.01%;
    }

100.01%, not a hack or a kludge, has been around for many years. Google "100.01%" and read up. It is as valid as 100% and does cover some territory 100% doesn't.

An initial font-size should always be declared. Set a base font-size on an outer container -- either <html> or <body> -- for it is from that container which all relative and inherited font-size values will derive. Using 100% or 100.01% makes the starting font-size equal to the user's browser preference.

Setting that base font-size to the user's browser preference gives your visitors maximum readability. Read that again, please, about the USER's preference. Your visitor will have set their browser font-size for their own best legibility and reading comfort. Your design, magnificent and fragile though it may be, is only a second-string player. Content is king, assuming you have some. But if that content is un-readably tiny, you lose. The visitor surfs on. Your design, then, has failed your needs and your expectations. Therefore, the design really wasn't all that great, was it?

Comment: Being valid doesn't stop it being a hack. You state that "an initial font-size should always be declared" — but you don't state why. Browsers have a default (which is the user's preference).