# Is using font-size: 100.01% still needed, and for what browsers?

Tags: css, cross-browser

I'm cleaning up some old and terrible css, which includes:

```
body {
  font-size: 100.01%
}
```

While researching, I found [body { font-size: 100.01%; } vs body { font-size: 100%; }?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703056/body-font-size-100-01-vs-body-font-size-100), which explains the reason for setting font-size to 100.01%, but doesn't tell what browsers this 'fix' targets.

Do any modern browsers still face this issue, and if so, which and what versions?

Comment: That question actually does say what browsers the fix targets: "older versions of Opera and Safari"

Comment: Chuck - Would you say it's ok to assume Opera 9 and older, and Safari 4 and older?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answer taken from *[CSS: Getting Into Good Coding Habits](http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?page=5&cid=FAF76)* by Adrian Senior

> This odd 100.01% value for the font
>   size compensates for several browser
>   bugs. First, setting a default body
>   font size in percent (instead of em)
>   eliminates an IE/Win problem with
>   growing or shrinking fonts out of
>   proportion if they are later set in
>   ems in other elements. Additionally,
>   some versions of Opera will draw a
>   default font-size of 100% too small
>   compared to other browsers. Safari, on
>   the other hand, has a problem with a
>   font-size of 101%. The current "best"
>   suggestion is to use the 100.01% value
>   for this property.